# scala compile error ：match argument types when Jersey Client register

Tags: scala, http, jersey

```
val config = new ClientConfig()
val feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("ab", "cd")
val client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config)
client.register(feature)
val responds: Response = client.target("http://10.0.2.110:8080")
    .path("helloworld")
    .request()
    .get()

println(responds.readEntity(classOf[String]))
```

IDEA shows compile error:
Error:(18, 12) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method register in trait Configurable of type (x$1: Any, x$2: Class[_]*)javax.ws.rs.client.Client
and  method register in trait Configurable of type (x$1: Any)javax.ws.rs.client.Client
match argument types (org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature)
    client.register(feature)

But I run it in java ,it was fine.

```
    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("ab", "cd");
    final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    client.register(feature);
    Response responds  = client.target("http://10.0.2.110:8080")
        .path("helloworld")
        .request()
        .get();
    System.out.printf(responds.readEntity(String.class));
```

Comment: Just as the reference to understand the Scala overloading better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829114/ambiguous-reference-to-overloaded-definition-one-vs-two-parameters

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
client.register(feature, Seq(): _*)
```

[calling java varargs from scala with overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735648/calling-java-varargs-from-scala-with-overloading)

Comment: I have just change overloading method.


client.register(feature,1)


it works fine.